# Steps for moving or migrating Magento 2 to AWS EC2 and servers versions

Tags: migration, magento2.2, server-setup, aws, amazon-web-services

I need to migrate and move a Magento 2.2 store to EC2 on AWS.

Q1- is there a step by step (updated) guide for doing so? most of the googled results are out-dated, non of them mentioned the point in the second questions.

Q2 - Do i have to maintain the same SQL, Apache, PHP ..etc versions on the new server to match the old ones on the older server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to AWS means, that you have to configure the following resources:

- RDS - This is your Database Server.
- Autoscaling Group - The autoscaling group makes sure horizontal scaling does work. Even if you plan to launch a single ec2 instance, you should use an autoscaling group. This is common best practice.
- Launch Configuration - The launch configuration is the recipe for your ec2 instances. You will describe the server type (e.g., m4.large) and the user_data. The User Data can be a single bash script that installs everything on your servers as soon as they launch.
- Security Groups - In a security group you define who is allowed to talk to each other. ec2 can talk to rds. Everyone can talk to ec2. Noone (except ec2) can talk to rds.
- VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) - Each account has a default vpc that you can use. If you like to use a more secure way, you should set up your own VPC's.
- Elasticache - This is basically redis or memcache as a service. You can handle it the same way like rds.
- Loadbalancer - You'll need the load balancer in order to work with multiple instances.

**Don't fall into the Pitfall**

In case you use an autoscaling group, you will run into a common issue. Images are normally stored on the filesystem of an ec2 instance. In an autoscaling group, everything has to be immutable, because your instances will die from time to time and they will come back again. If an instance dies, your uploaded images (e.g., in the CMS Section) will be lost. Therefore, you should configure an S3 Bucket. Store your images there.

**Tip**
Instead of clicking on the AWS Admin Console, you should use a tool like [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/). Due to terraform, it is possible to work with "Infrastructure as Code". Your infrastructure lives inside of your codebase and therefore, you do have all the benefits that come with git and other tools.

**Shameless Plug**

I am currently developing a [terraform Magento 2 AWS Stack](https://github.com/DavidLambauer/magento2-aws-terraform). It is not yet finished, but there are updates frequently. Even if you don't use it, you might want to have a look at the resources I use in the .tf files.

As soon your server is up and running, you can upgrade the SQL and the PHP Versions. There should be no problems doing that, as long Magento supports the version you like to use.

**Caution**

If you are not familiar with Cloud Concepts, you should start reading about it first. There are many problems you could run into, e.g., deployment, rollbacks and so on.

Comment: updated version @
https://github.com/magenx/Magento-2-aws-cluster-terraform